# Reference to shared pointer becomes corrupted

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

Reference to shared pointer becomes corrupted even though shared_ptr is still owned.

I have something like the following code snippet in an application and keep getting dangling references to pointers or some other corruption when trying to use references to a shared_ptr inside of a class object. The below benchmark also exhibits the same problem on RHEL7 using gcc 5.4.0. It also happens with clang 4.0.1. I've verified that the shared_ptr never actually destructs the pointed to object until the system exits.

When storing a shared_ptr in A things work just fine.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Int
{
  public:
    Int() : Int(0) { }
    Int(int v) : _val(v) { }
    int val() const { return _val; }
    ~Int() { }

  private:
    int _val;
};

typedef shared_ptr<Int> IntPtr;

class A
{
  public:
    IntPtr &intPtr;
    A() = delete;
    A(IntPtr &int_ptr) : intPtr(int_ptr)
    {
        cout << "A()" << endl;
        cout << intPtr.use_count() << endl;
        cout << intPtr->val() << endl;
    }
};

class B
{
  public:
    B(A *a) : _a(a) { }
    B() = delete;
    A *_a;
};

vector<IntPtr> intPtrs;

A* makeNew()
{
    IntPtr int_ptr = make_shared<Int>(44883);
    intPtrs.push_back(int_ptr);
    cout << "makeNew()" << endl;
    cout << intPtrs.back().use_count() << endl;
    cout << intPtrs.back()->val() << endl;
    A *a = new A(int_ptr);

    return a;
}

void checkB(B *b)
{
    A *a = b->_a;
    assert(a);
    cout << "checkB()" << endl;
    cout << a->intPtr.use_count() << endl;
    cout << a->intPtr->val() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    B *b = new B(makeNew());
    checkB(b);
    cout << "main()" << endl;
    A *a = b->_a;
    cout << a->intPtr.use_count() << endl;
    cout << a->intPtr->val() << endl;

    cout << "intPtrs size: " << intPtrs.size() << endl;

    for (const auto &int_ptr : intPtrs) {
        cout << int_ptr.use_count() << endl;
        cout << int_ptr->val() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

makeNew()
2
44883
A()
2
44883
checkB()
-324888
-610139856
main()
-610139968
-1066293104
intPtrs size: 1
1
44883

Above is the generated output, as can be seen in checkB() or when checking the newly created object in main() I get garbage.

Because the vector is the owner of the IntPtr and has a lifetime that lasts until the program ends, I would expect the reference in A to be fine.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your code with `asan` and/or running it with `valgrind` yet?

Comment: You store a reference to the local `int_ptr`, so what did you expect? `Because the vector is the owner of the IntPtr and has a lifetime that lasts until the program ends, I would expect the reference in A to be fine.` The vector owns it's own instance of `shared_ptr`, this doesn't keep the other instance alive.

Answer (score 1):

`makeNew` returns a pointer to an `A` which contains a reference to an `IntPtr`; but this `IntPtr` is already destroyed, it was a local variable in `makeNew`. So the reference becomes invalid.

I would assume `shared_ptr` reference counting works when you assign the ptr to another variable, but not when you keep a reference to it.